# Create states from json file / http

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a backend which is generating a json file containing information about the most important pages. I would like to load this json file, and build corresponding states based on the data in the file. I can't inject $stateProvider into .run or .controller, and I can't inject $http into .config, so I am feeling a bit lost.

So the question is. How I can load a json file, go through the data and build states based on this data?

Quick edit: If I am lacking in providing the necessary information, please tell, and I'll try and improve the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've attempted to solve a similar problem and created UI-Router Extras "Future States".  Future states tries to solve additional problems, such as lazy loading using RequireJS, placeholders for entire unloaded modules, and routing by bookmarked URL to unloaded placeholders.

Here is a plunk demonstrating how to use Future States for your use case: http://plnkr.co/edit/Ny7MQcmy35dKeEjbw57d?p=preview

I tried using the stackoverflow snippet runner, but had problems, so here is a non-runnable paste of the code.

JS:

```js
// Code goes here

var app = angular.module("jsonstates", ["ct.ui.router.extras"]);

app.config([ '$stateProvider', '$futureStateProvider', 
function($sp, $fsp ) { 
  var futureStateResolve = function($http) { 
    return $http.get("states.json").then(function(response) {
      angular.forEach(response.data, function(state) { 
        $sp.state(state);
      })
    })
  }
  $fsp.addResolve(futureStateResolve);
  console.log($fsp);
}]);

app.controller("someCtrl", function() { })
```

Html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.25" data-semver="1.2.25" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.25/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-router/0.2.11/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/christopherthielen/ui-router-extras/0.0.10/release/ct-ui-router-extras.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="jsonstates">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <a href="#/top">Top state</a> <a href="#/top/nested">Nested state</a>
    <div ui-view></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Json:

```
[
  { 
    "name": "top",
    "url": "/top",
    "controller": "someCtrl",
    "template": "<h1>top state</h1><div ui-view></div>"
  },
  { 
    "name": "nested",
    "parent": "top",
    "url": "/nested",
    "controller": "someCtrl",
    "template": "<h1>nested state</h1><div ui-view></div>"
  }
]
```

Comment: Will this work when visiting a state directly before the future states has been loaded? Example website.com/nested as in your json.

Comment: Yes, Future States delays UI-Router from routing until all the `$fsp.addResolve` promises are resolved.

Comment: This is very close to what I was looking for except I need to use a templateURL so I can load from $templateCache and not an inline html markup applied to the template property. Also Can I define states as abstract using views?

Any ideas how i can do this using what you have demonstrated, thanks for your time and patience. I really need to get a route loaded dynamically from json with the above criteria.

Comment: Did you try it? templateUrl should work. Anything you can declare in a standard state definition can be declared in JSON, except for functions.

Comment: Yeah here is my json:

[
 {
  "name": "unauth",
  "url": "/",
  "controller": "LoginCtrl",
  "templateURL": "app/components/core/login/login.html"
 }
]

Comment: Silly me, I'm sorry i spelled 'templateURL' wrong and it should instead have been 'templateUrl'. Now i'll try and get abstract and views next.

Comment: It works great so far with views, nesting and abstract. Thanks Chris T and all contributers above

Comment: I've tried using the $futureState after my app has loaded, like so:

$futureState.state({
      name: 'module1.sub',
      url: '/wtf',
      templateUrl: "<div>GAWWWDDDDD DAMMMMIT PLEASE REGISTER!!!!!</div>"
     });

But it will not load!!! :(

Comment: Chris T, ('Knowing you are the author of ui-routes-extras') I feel like I'm missing something obvious here. I've been banging my head all day long on this and have had no luck. Not sure how I should approach this problem or if i should create an entirely new question via stack overflow for you, but def need help adding new role based states after app has already loaded via a json file in a controller i have. really, any help is massively appreciated!

Comment: I guess a working example of your 'adminModuleFutureState'. what should i do with this future state admin object?

var adminModuleFutureState = {
    stateName: 'app.admin',
    urlPrefix: '/app/pages/admin',
    type: 'ngload',
    routeFragment: '/admin', // example custom attr
    src: 'js/modules/admin.js' // example custom attr
}

Comment: holy crap, post a question

Comment: Chris, I added a new question in hopes to both explain in better detail what my issue is with adding states post load after a user has authenticated, essentially decorating existing states and see if you might know what I'm doing wrong.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26497743/ui-router-extras-cant-attach-add-new-futurestate-objects-after-app-conf